# NoReverseMatch following v1.9 to v1.10 upgrade

Tags: python, django

I've just upgraded to django v1.10 and I'm running through tests to check everything works fine but I've getting `Reverse for 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` on my login page.

I'm using django-registration and have made a call to get the login page using `<a href="/accounts/login/">Login</a>`.

I then get the error message against this the html and it is `<form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">` which is throwing up the error.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
          <form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
            <span style="color:green">{{msg}}</span><br>
            <table align="center">{{ form }}</table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Login</button>
          </form>
          <a href="/password/recover" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Forgotten Password</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've not changed urls.py which looks includes:

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.hmac.urls')),
```

I've changed nothing going from 1.9 to 1.10 (and what I changed trying to fix this I've reverted).  Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Django 1.10 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10):

> The ability to **reverse()** URLs using a dotted Python path is removed.

The `url` template tag uses `reverse()`. Thus this is **not valid anymore**:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}
```

You must use the route name.

See [Django 1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.8/#passing-a-dotted-path-to-reverse-and-url) for details.

Comment: You must use the route name, which should be `'login'`.